# How to check range/column of cells based on month and copy them

Tags: excel, vba, date, copy, range

So essentially, what I'm trying to do is this:

```
------A--------B-------C-------D------
1  Date       Weight   Misc     ID*
2  2014-06-12 210              445556
3  2014-07-13 150              546456
4  2014-08-14 265              546456 
5  2014-09-15 655              655654
6  2014-10-16 87               546656
7  2014-10-17 1552             545488
8  2014-11-18 225              546545
```

I have a button and I want it to run a macro that checks if the dates in Column A fall within the current month. I've tried using

```
Month(Date)
```

but it checks the entire date, not the month only.

If the month in the cell in colmumn A equals the current month, I want it to copy the entire row of information corresponding to that particular cell. For example: When the current month is november, I want it to copy A8+B8+C8+D8, then I will paste that information in a whole different workbook.

Keep in mind that I'm completely new to VBA, but this is what I've come up with so far:

```
Sub dat()
Dim rng As Range
Dim dat As Date
dat = Month(Date)
For Each rng In Range("A2:A100")
If rng.Value = dat Then
Range("???").Copy
Range("A1").PasteSpecial
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Nothing really happens. If I change it to `dat=Date` then it only works for this particular day, and it takes forever to run through 1000 cells.

I was thinking if I could use `Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Value = Month(Date)` somehow. Is this even possible?

**EDIT:** To paste in a different workbook I used the following commands:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\....DOCUMENT.xlsm")
```

And then to paste:

```
wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & NextDest & ":F" & NextDest).PasteSpecial
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the "Destination Sheet" to the name of the sheet you want to copy to.

```
Sub dat()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim CurRow As Long
    Dim NextDest As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("SOURCE SHEET")
    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For CurRow = 2 To LastRow
        If IsDate(ws.Range("A" & CurRow).Value) = True Then
            If Month(ws.Range("A" & CurRow).Value) = Month(Date) Then
                ws.Range("A" & CurRow & ":D" & CurRow).Copy
                NextDest = Sheets("DESTINATION SHEET").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                Sheets("DESTINATION SHEET").Range("A" & NextDest & ":D" & NextDest).PasteSpecial
                Else
            End If
        Else
            ws.Cells(CurRow, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255,0,0)
        End If
    Next CurRow
End Sub
```

Edit: Your DESTINATION SHEET will now add rows after the last used row.  Also, the code will check if the value is a date first and will highlight if not a date.

Comment: Thank you both very much.

Chris, your solution worked pretty much as I requested. There is one issue, however. It only copies & pastes the first row of cells with data that match the criteria (i.e. this month). In my actual database, I have several hundreds of rows, with about 100 each month so I need it to run through all of these and copy all of the cells that match the specified criteria.

Comment: @nuke My edit above should help.  I defined the source sheet in case of issues with losing focus on source sheet.  Let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: Well, that's more or less exactly what I was trying to achieve. A big thanks to you kind sir! I altered the code so the macro pastes the copied data in a different workbook, not a different sheet (see edit of 1st post).

The mechanics of the month(date) command are still somewhat unclear to me. I've attemped to use it in a different environment, but I failed to make it work the way you did (which is my intention). I'm mostly trying to use it with If *certain year/month/day etc..* Then. I tried changing Month = Date() in your code to different serials, e.g. 2 for february, but to no avail.

Comment: Try `Dim MyMonth As Integer`, use a `InputBox` to get the number of the month you want to check, and change the code to `= Month(DateSerial(Year(Date), MyMonth, Day(Date))`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that!

One last question and I'll stop bugging you ;-). Is there any way to change the starting position of the If Month(ws.Range("A" & CurRow).Value) = Month(Date) ? So it begins the counting process further down the column than cell A1? I have a header in my source sheet which causes an error since it's not a date.

Comment: Did a couple updates.  Now checks to make sure the cells are a Date format.  If not, they are highlighted for your attention.  Let me know if this works.

Comment: Hi and thanks again. I changed the If `IsDate(ws.Range("A" & CurRow).Value) is True Then` to `If IsDate(ws.Range("A" & CurRow).Value) = True Then` since I was getting Type mismatch errors. Thank a lot, you've saved me a lot of hours of work!

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
       If rng.Value = dat Then
```

To

```
     If month(rng.Value) = dat Then
```